# mssql parse nested xml

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have an xml message that I need to get the test information out of and into a table using a stored procedure.

I've been using this query:

```
select distinct 
    'N' as ORIGSTS, 
    doc1.Samples.value('(ID)[1]', 'nvarchar(20)') as 'SAMPLE_ID', 
    doc2.Tests.value('(Name)[1]', 'nvarchar(20)') as 'TEST_NAME' 
from
    @messageXml.nodes('/CDFAOrderMsg/Samples/Sample') as doc1(Samples), 
    @messageXml.nodes('/CDFAOrderMsg/Samples/Sample/Tests/Test') as doc2(Tests)
where doc1.Samples.value('(ID)[1]', 'nvarchar(20)') = 456
order by 2, 3
```

The problem is that it returns the sample ID 456 along with all tests listed in the message. I need to be able to extract the test names along with their associated sample Id to insert into a table. Currently, with two samples and three tests each it returns 12 rows when it should only return 6.

How can I make it return a list of all samples along with their respective test names?

Thanks,

Scott

```
<OrderMsg xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Samples>
    <SourceType>Non-Animal</SourceType>
    <Sample>
      <ID>456</ID>
      <Tests>
        <Test>
          <Name>SPC</Name>
        </Test>
        <Test>
          <Name>COL</Name>
        </Test>
        <Test>
          <Name>ANTI</Name>
        </Test>
      </Tests>
    </Sample>
    <Sample>
      <ID>457</ID>
      <Tests>
        <Test>
          <Name>HPC</Name>
        </Test>
        <Test>
          <Name>DEL</Name>
        </Test>
        <Test>
          <Name>NVT</Name>
        </Test>
      </Tests>
    </Sample>
  </Samples>
</OrderMsg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a query that gives the expected result using a outer apply function to get the child nodes collection.

```
DECLARE @x xml
SET @x = '<OrderMsg xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <Samples>
        <SourceType>Non-Animal</SourceType>
        <Sample>
          <ID>456</ID>
          <Tests>
            <Test>
              <Name>SPC</Name>
            </Test>
            <Test>
              <Name>COL</Name>
            </Test>
            <Test>
              <Name>ANTI</Name>
            </Test>
          </Tests>
        </Sample>
        <Sample>
          <ID>457</ID>
          <Tests>
            <Test>
              <Name>HPC</Name>
            </Test>
            <Test>
              <Name>DEL</Name>
            </Test>
            <Test>
              <Name>NVT</Name>
            </Test>
          </Tests>
        </Sample>
      </Samples>
    </OrderMsg>'

SELECT DISTINCT
  'N' AS ORIGSTS,
  s.sampleNode.query('ID').value('.', 'nvarchar(20)') AS 'SAMPLE_ID',
  t.testNode.query('Test/Name').value('.', 'nvarchar(20)') AS 'TEST_NAME'
FROM @x.nodes('//Samples/Sample') s (sampleNode)
OUTER APPLY (SELECT
  x.testNode.query('.') testNode
FROM sampleNode.nodes('Tests/Test') x (testNode)) t
WHERE s.sampleNode.value('(ID)[1]', 'nvarchar(20)') = 456
ORDER BY 2, 3
```

Comment: Thank you!! That works great! I'm not entirely sure how it works so I'll have to read up on it but thank you!